# problema con el hover css

Tags: css, hover, overflow

Bien, tengo una tabla de registro con las calificaciones de estudiantes, ahora, cada uno de estos registros se encuentran dentro de un elemento con la clase **alumno** y esta clase tiene un **:hover** en CSS, y la idea es que cuando se pose sobre la clase **alumno** entonces cambie de color toda la fila.

Ahora el problema, como la tabla es demasiado larga para entrar en la pantalla le puse al contenedor un **overflow en x** para que puedan desplazarse hacia la derecha para ver el resto de los registros, pero cuando pasa eso, el resto de esa fila que deberia estar coloreada, no lo está.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de toda la tabla es demasiado largo para ponerlo, pero si alguien tiene alguna idea de a que se debe, por favor me ayudaria mucho

Answer (score 0):

Bien, no sé a que se debe, pero, se como solucionar el problema.
Basicamente, cuando declares el **hover** solo tienes que decirle que le afectará a todos los hijos de ese elemento con un *

```
... .alumno:hover *{
 
Aqui escribes todo tu codigo... en mi caso un "background:var(--skyblue);
 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]